How to hot reload php process when changes are detected?
I'm developing a PHP script and everytime I make a change on the code I have to restart the script/process manually, is there any method for hot reloading a PHP script being runned on CLI mode ?

There is no automatic way to do that.

It's not possible in php directly, you'll have to pass through an external tool as described for example in this answer : https://superuser.com/a/181543

Recommended answer that matches OP request the most
Using a file pointer to store an MD5 of the file being executed on load, then checking if that MD5 changes in your infinite loop, you can effectively reboot the process when changes occur.
//place at the top of your infinately running script as soon as it first executes:
file_put_contents('masterprocessmd5', md5(__FILE__));

//place this in your loop
if (md5(__FILE__) != file_get_contents('masterprocessmd5')) {
    //master process changed, reboot
    exec("php your_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    exit;
}

Original Response - with multiple other ideas
Apologies if I misunderstand but it's not really great to have a script running indefinitely, if it crashes or etc then you have to go restart it back up.
You should instead have a cron setup to fire the process up every 5 minutes for example, and code your script to run for up to 5 mins and terminate.
This will mean a constant fresh execution.
Run php loop for 5 minutes then stop:
<?php
$startTime = time(); // Get the current time

while (true) {
    // Your code here

    // Check if 5 minutes have passed
    if (time() - $startTime >= (5*60)) {
        break; // Exit the loop after 5 minutes
    }
}
?>

UPDATE (SEE COMMENTS)
Ok so rightly so, you might prefer an ever running script. Here are 2 more ideas:
(1) As I have mentioned in the comments, you might want to have that script doing far less and fire up other processes to handle the actual logic of the requests perhaps?
(2) Add some logic to your script to see when a file exists, lets call it "restartmasterprocess", whenever this file is seen in your infinitely running script you can delete the file, start a new process using exec() or shell_exec() and then end execution.
if (file_exists('restartmasterprocess')) {
    unlink('restartmasterprocess');
    exec("php your_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    exit;
}

If you want to totally automate this we could in fact add an md5 to the file then use that to detect changes?
//place at the top of your infinately running script as soon as it first executes:
file_put_contents('masterprocessmd5', md5(__FILE__));

//place this in your loop
if (md5(__FILE__) != file_get_contents('masterprocessmd5')) {
    //master process changed, reboot
    exec("php your_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    exit;
}


Yes and no. Most applications which run as a service/daemon are designed to run indefinitely, so that the service is always available. It depends what the purpose of the OP's program is, which of course we don't know

I guess in that case the service/daemon needs to have less logic in it and when it receiver's a request fire up a separate script to handle that request.
Personally I wouldn't ever have something running indefinitely, but I can see perhaps cases where you might want to, but personally I wouldn't have that doing too much itself if that was the case.

Again it depends what you're writing. If you're building a webserver, or something which has to listen to messages on a queue in real-time and do something with the information, then you certainly want that to be able to run indefinitely without interruption or needing to be restarted or scheduled - it needs to be available at any time. And, again, we don't know if the OP's code falls into that category.

But even if it has a fairly short run-time, less than a few minutes maybe, I can still see the wish, when developing, to may be able to restart itself immediately when the underlying file changes. Your solution doesn't fully achieve that, although splitting the script up might, with the disadvantage that having to exec another script adds indirection and points of failure, but potentially modularises it more nicely. I wouldn't design it like that just to make dev/test better though, if there's no need for such flexibility in production.

Totally agree, have updated answer with the idea above and also another idea using a file to determine restart. Guess its over to the OP!

Just had another idea to totally automate the process of restarting the process. thoughts?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It's neater, but again I wouldn't do that just to faciliate slightly easier development, it would need to be a useful feature in itself. A better solution to this IMO would be for the OP to write a deployment script, triggered by a commit of the script to the relevant branch in their source code repository, which automatically deploys the script to is runnable location, ends any currently running process using that script file, and starts a new one

yes that would also be nice if they are using such features, but assuming they are just editing the file directly - without real clarification of the process the OP goes through I guess we are just guessing on solutions, pretty happy with my 3 ideas...
